# Transposing a table and setting row labels manually

Tags: tables

I am new on this forum and have a question about transposing data with the `pgfplotstable` package. I have found a post explaining how to transpose a table and have tried to make modifications using the documentation but I am not managing to find the right commands.

I have an input CSV file which contains a series of values (one line only):

`2016-06-13 05:00,6.2,5305,849,29.0,160,1,160`

I want to use LaTeX

1. to read the file,
2. generate a vertical table with the values, and
3. assign an arbitrary name for each line of the output table.

The code I have for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[
    col sep=comma,
]{test.csv}\normal

\pgfplotstabletranspose[
%    header=false
    input colnames to={colA,colB}
]\transpose\normal

%\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
string type,
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
every col no 0/.style={
    column type={l},
    column name={Averages for the week},
    %postproc cell content/.append style={/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={Subj }{}},
    },
]\transpose

\end{document}
```

With this code, I get a table with only one column (and some text appended at the end of the last row "index7"), whereas I would like to have something like this (where I define in the TEX file names for each rows:

[image: wanted output]

Is it possible to do this?

Thank you very much in advance for your replies.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Nice question. Rather than posting code fragments it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents,stackengine,booktabs}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
2016-06-13 05:00,6.2,5305,849,29.0,160,1,160
\end{filecontents*}
\setstackEOL{,}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\def\sepdata#1,#2\relax{\def\Week{#1}\def\datalist{#2}}
\newcommand\readparsedef[1]{\readdef{#1}{\data}\expandafter\sepdata\data\relax}
\begin{document}
\readparsedef{mydata.dat}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
Averages for the week starting & \Week\\
\midrule
\Longstack[l]{Row Name1,
Row Name2,
Row Name3,
Row Name4,
Row Name5,
Row Name6,
Row Name7} & 
\expandafter\Longstack\expandafter{\datalist}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using \pgfplotstable, just very very difficult.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents,booktabs}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.dat}
2016-06-13 05:00,6.2,5305,849,29.0,160,1,160
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false,string type]{
Averages for week starting,RowName1,RowName2,RowName3,RowName4,RowName5,RowName6,RowName7
}\names% create column names
\fbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\names}% debug

\pgfplotstableread[
    header=false,
    col sep=comma,
    string type
]{test.dat}\normal
\fbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\normal}% debug

\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\normal
\let\mydate=\pgfplotsretval% will become column name later
\mydate% debug

\pgfplotstablevertcat\names\normal
\fbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,]\names}% debug

\pgfplotstabletranspose[header=false,colnames from=0]\transpose\names
\fbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\transpose}% debug

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,columns={Averages for week starting,\mydate},
  columns/Averages for week starting/.style={column type=l},
  columns/\mydate/.style={column type=r},
  ]\transpose

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]